# ScrollView Won't Scroll AHHH

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

For the life of me I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. All I'm trying to do is put a bunch of text fields in a scroll view and have it intrinsically determine the contentSize using auto layout. Unlike the other tutorials I've watched and read out there, I'm trying to do this programmatically, not through Storyboards or Xibs.

I've called `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` on every view in the scroll view (including on the scroll view itself).

I've set the `height` and `width` of the scroll view to match it's superview and even positioned the scroll view in the center of it's superview (I read that sometimes you need to do that to get it working)

I've pinned the content view's edges to the `top`, `leading`, `trailing`, and `bottom` edges of it's superview (the scroll view)

Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var scrollView = UIScrollView()
    var contentView = UIView()

    var textField1 = CustomTextField()
    var textField2 = CustomTextField()
    var textField3 = CustomTextField()
    var textField4 = CustomTextField()
    var textField5 = CustomTextField()
    var textField6 = CustomTextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        textField1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        textField2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        textField3.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        textField4.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        textField5.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        textField6.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.addSubview(textField1)
        contentView.addSubview(textField2)
        contentView.addSubview(textField3)
        contentView.addSubview(textField4)
        contentView.addSubview(textField5)
        contentView.addSubview(textField6)

        contentView.backgroundColor = .redColor()

        setupConstraints()
    }

    func setupConstraints() {
        // Install height and width constraints on our scroll view
        let heightLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let widthLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        self.view.addConstraints([heightLC,widthLC])

        // Install centering constraints on our scroll view
        let centerXLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let centerYLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        self.view.addConstraints([centerXLC,centerYLC])

        // Set the content view so it resizes with the same proportions on screen rotations //
        let contentViewTopLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let contentViewLeadingLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let contentViewTrailingLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let contentViewBottomLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let contentViewWidthLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let contentViewHeightLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        scrollView.addConstraints([contentViewTopLC,contentViewLeadingLC,contentViewTrailingLC,contentViewBottomLC,contentViewWidthLC,contentViewHeightLC])

        // Setup the text field constraints
        let textField1Top : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let textField1Leading : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40)
        let textField1Trailing : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -40)
        contentView.addConstraints([textField1Top, textField1Leading, textField1Trailing])

        let textField2Top : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: textField1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
        let textField2Leading : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40)
        let textField2Trailing : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -40)
        contentView.addConstraints([textField2Top, textField2Leading, textField2Trailing])

        let textField3Top : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField3, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: textField2, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
        let textField3Leading : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField3, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40)
        let textField3Trailing : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField3, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -40)
        contentView.addConstraints([textField3Top, textField3Leading, textField3Trailing])

        let textField4Top : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField4, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: textField3, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
        let textField4Leading : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField4, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40)
        let textField4Trailing : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField4, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -40)
        contentView.addConstraints([textField4Top, textField4Leading, textField4Trailing])

        let textField5Top : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField5, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: textField4, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
        let textField5Leading : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField5, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40)
        let textField5Trailing : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField5, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -40)
        contentView.addConstraints([textField5Top, textField5Leading, textField5Trailing])

        let textField6Top : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField6, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: textField5, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
        let textField6Leading : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField6, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40)
        let textField6Trailing : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField6, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -40)
        let textField6Bottom : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField6, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        contentView.addConstraints([textField6Top, textField6Leading, textField6Trailing, textField6Bottom])
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()


        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

And here's my `CustomTextField` class I use for the text fields:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

        // set text field height to 55pts
        let heightLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 55)
        addConstraint(heightLC)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Here's what the app currently looks like 
(notice the 6th text field isn't being displayed and I can't scroll down to it):

Any help will greatly be appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the scrollView's contentSize property? That's the first thing I think of. I'm not sure how it interacts with constraints, but it might not get set up implicitly.

Comment: Yeah scrollView.contentSize prints (0.0, 0.0). Any ideas why it's not being set implicitly?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind. Could you accomplish what you're trying to achieve with a UITableView? Otherwise, you'd have to compute the size and set it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is these lines:

```
    let contentViewTopLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let contentViewLeadingLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let contentViewTrailingLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let contentViewBottomLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let contentViewWidthLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let contentViewHeightLC : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    scrollView.addConstraints([contentViewTopLC,contentViewLeadingLC,contentViewTrailingLC,contentViewBottomLC,contentViewWidthLC,contentViewHeightLC])
```

What you want is not for the content view to be *sized like* the scroll view at all. That is exactly what is *keeping* the scroll view from scrolling. You want the content view's four edges to be pinned to the four edges of the scroll view.

That way, the contents of the content view will push *outwards* on the content view, sizing it. It will thus try to become *bigger* than the scroll view. But it can't, because you're also going to pin the sides of the scroll view to *its* superview. Thus, the content view's size will become the *bounds size* of the scroll view - its `contentSize`. When the `contentSize` of the scroll view is thus bigger than the scroll view, it will be scrollable.

Comment: You say you can't find examples that do it all in code. Clearly you haven't read my book, since that is exactly the approach it takes. In this example from my book, you should concentrate on "case 3" - it lays out the entire thing with auto layout, in code. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch07p363scrollViewInCode3/ch20p670scrollViewInCode3/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt. So basicall you're saying to just remove the contentViewWidthLC and contentViewHeightLC constraints, and add 4 constraints to pin the content view to the scroll view's edges? I'm only reiterating this cause that's what I tried but still no luck. Nothing appears on my screen when I do that

Comment: Look at the example! It shows you all four combinations of autolayout / no autolayout when using a content view. Download it. Run it. Copy it.

Comment: "you're saying to just remove" I didn't say "just remove" anything. All of those constraints are wrong. The content view must be pinned to all four edges of the scroll view. And then _its_ contents must be _fully_ constrained on all four sides to push _outwards_ to dictate the content size.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand constraints, but I thought the `contentViewTopLC`, `contentViewLeadingLC`, `contentViewTrailingLC`, and `contentViewBottomLC` were pinning the contentView to the 4 edges of the scroll view.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. If my answer didn't solve the problem, why did you accept it?

Comment: It did solve the problem, so thank you for that. I took your code and was able to get a scroll view working, but I was just trying to figure out how to get my original code working so I can understand scroll views and constraints better.

Comment: Well, those four constraints may have been okay, but the "equal width" and "equal height" constraints were then overkill and wrecking everything. Compare your current code to your old code; if your current code is working, you can see what the difference is. I can't see your new code so I can't comment.